# Set-ACL rules for child objects

Tags: powershell, file-permissions

I have a PowerShell script to create a directory (if it doesn't already exist), and then make sure that only SYSTEM and local admin accounts have access:

```
#Create directory if it does not already exist
$path = "C:\MyDirectory"
[System.IO.Directory]::CreateDirectory($path)

$acl = Get-Acl $path
$acl.SetAccessRuleProtection($true,$false)

$System = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule("SYSTEM","FullControl","Allow")
$acl.SetAccessRule($System)

$Admins = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule("BUILTIN\Administrators","FullControl","Allow")
$acl.SetAccessRule($Admins)

$rules = $acl.access | Where-Object { 
    (-not $_.IsInherited) -and 
    $_.IdentityReference -like "AD\*" 
}
ForEach($rule in $rules) {
    $acl.RemoveAccessRule($rule) | Out-Null
}

$acl | Set-Acl $path
```

At the end, I remove rights granted to any domain user that may have been granted access previously. This works fine for the parent level `C:\MyDirectory` but all child objects (subfolders and files) don't receive any permissions:

[image: Example file ACL, showing no user has any permissions]

I don't want `C:\MyDirectory` to inherit permissions from `C:\`, but I do want subfolders and subfiles of `C:\MyDirectory` to inherit from `C:\MyDirectory`.

What can I do to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `InheritanceFlags` and `PropagationFlags` properties on the new rules. The default is that they don't get inherited (`None`).

```
$System = [System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule]::new(
  "SYSTEM",
  "FullControl",
  "ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit", # inheritanceFlags
  "InheritOnly", # propagationFlags
  "Allow"
)
```

Depending on what you're going for, you may also want to set the folder owner.